# Fetch, split, re-arrange, output

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have dates stored as strings in a SQL Server 2000 database like this:

```
01/01/2017
```

I need to fetch, split, re-arrange and output it to a `.csv` like this:

```
2017-01-01
```

I have been playing with `REPLACE` and `CONVERT` functions but none seems to do what I need it to do. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Why not `Cast` the value as `datetime` and then use `Format` to spit it back out in your desired format?  See SQL Fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d97cf/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick...

```
DECLARE @DateString VARCHAR(15) = '1/1/2015';

SELECT ReformattedDate = CONVERT(CHAR(10), CAST(@DateString AS DATETIME), 21);
```

returns...

```
ReformattedDate
---------------
2015-01-01
```